# XtraBackup Restore Full Backup OK but I can't initialize mysqld

Tags: backup, xtrabackup

I'm using XtraBackup mode Streaming and Compressing Backups to perform my backup on a MariaDB 10.19:

```
$ innobackupex --user=$db_user --password=$db_pass --compact --stream=tar ./ --no-timestamp | gzip - > $WORKING_DIR/$BCK_FILE
```

All seems ok even when I restore the backup, innobackup output shows:

```
...
innobackupex: Finished copying back files.

160801 13:52:31  innobackupex: completed OK!
```

but when I start the mysqld I find the next message in its log:

```
2016-08-01 15:52:33 7f08d8ed87c0 InnoDB: Error: page 371 log sequence number 2340146
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 2337804.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
...
a lot of times!
```

In some cases I can't initialize the mysql.

On the page 23 of the manual 'PerconaXtraBackup-2.1.9.pdf' you can read:
'Note that the streamed backup will need to be prepared before restoration. Streaming mode does not prepare the backup.'

I have no idea of how prepare the backup before the restoration in this situation.
In the manual explains how prepare it using --apply-log argument but the backups aren't performed using stream and compressing mode.

Anybody knows how prepare it correctly?

How can I retore it?

Should I use the --apply-log to prepare it? How?

Thanks for your time.

Best rgrds,

Boadrius

Answer (score 1):

In Manual itself it is explained that

1. Decompress backup

   ```
   $ innobackupex --decompress /data/backup/2013-08-01_11-24-04/
   ```
2. When the files are uncompressed you can prepare the backup with the --apply-log option:

   ```
   $ innobackupex --apply-log /data/backup/2013-08-01_11-24-04/
   ```

You should check for a confirmation message:

130802 02:51:02 innobackupex: completed OK!

Now the files in /data/backups/2013-08-01_11-24-04 is ready to be used by the server.

Comment: Note: Percona XtraBackup doesn’t automatically remove the compressed files. In order to clean up the backup
directory users should remove the *.qp files.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, in this case I don't use --apply-log to prepare the backup.
Though in my case I use --compact instead of --compress so I don't perform --decompress.
If I use stream and compact methods to perform the backup when I restore... it doesn't work.

Anybody knows if this two methods are compatible with each other?